# PIN locked Pixel with broken screen and USB debugging OFF, OTG keyboard doesn't unlock it

Tags: adb, broken-screen, usb-on-the-go, google-pixel, side-loading

I got a Google Pixel 1 with a smashed dead black screen locked by a known PIN that I would like to recover some photos from. Nothing vital but now it has become a personal crusade to do it!

The good news are:

- it shows as MTP device on win/linux
- vibrates if I try to unlock it via fingerprint (as it requires PIN, so no can do)
- if I connect a keyboard/mouse via OTG they do light up
- in recovery mode it shows in ADB and I'm even able to put it into sideload mode

The bad news:

- can't see sh1t (BTW Pixel 1 doesn't support USB-C -> HDMI)
- USB debugging is OFF
- if I enter my PIN via OTG+keyboard then plug it back to the PC, it stills shows as MTP and no files can be browsed (I would assumes it remains locked)

I'm pretty close to burn another 20 bucks and get a second spare screen but before I do that, any ideas?
From what I read, my greatest achievement so far which was to get it in sideload blindly is useless and every 3rd party tool seems to require USB debugging ON.

Thanks!

Comment: I assume bootloader is locked too. Given that you've already tried OTG solutions in vain and that USB debugging is already off, there is nothing else left to try. Get the screen replaced. Although there is a risk that the technician might just factory reset the device after replacing the screen (to get the screen unlocked), so that he/she can test that the new screen is reacting fine to the touches. // BTW, these photos that you are after, were they not automatically back up by Google Photos (assuming you had setup auto-backup and that you use Google Photos/accounts)?

Comment: As long as you can get into your phone (and the microphone/speaker works), accessibility options is another path. Have you tried to enable [Google Talkback](https://support.google.com/accessibility/android/answer/6007100?hl=en&ref_topic=10601570) and navigate your way to either copy the files off or enable Android developer mode. Tried a USB keyboard on my Pixel 2, but my 7-1 hub doesn't passthru data for ADB/MTP. For navigation, bluetooth keyboard may be better.

Comment: @Firelord yes mate, bootloader is locked. I know how to replace the screen, I think I was just unlucky in the Aliexpress lottery with the spare I got before. Regarding why auto-backup was OFF... yeah, I'm gonna think about an answer that doesn't make me look that stupid and come back to you.

Comment: @MorrisonChang if I got you right, your are suggesting using voice commands which are not enable on my phone and the only way to do it is past entering my PIN which is where I'm stuck! Given you got a Pixel 2 let me ask you, once your keyboard is connect, how do you unlock the screen? I mean keystroke commands. I've seen some videos where people press SPACE to bring the PIN input screen, others press ESC. Thanks.

Comment: For me I plug in USB keyboard, space bar twice (first to wake, second to get PIN keypad), type in PIN, press enter. On a Pixel 2, squeezing the sides launches "Ok/Hey Google". From there one can enable Talkback per my link. Just realized that I was depending on "squeeze frame to launch Google Assistant" feature which Pixel 1 doesn't have (and I left enabled). Without talkback it is rather hard to navigate via keyboard only (some areas like the notification shade seem impossible). If you had a music player running, you might be able to use media keys to verify interactivity. Not sure if useful.

Comment: @MorrisonChang yeah that didn't work with mine. Thanks for the help anyway. A new screen seems like the only way!